# Собственные методы в модели и общая модель Laravel

Tags: laravel

Как реализовать данный момент в Laravel используя Eloquent.Я уже задавал сегодня подобный вопрос,но не совсем точно его описал.Вот мне нужно подобное решение которое я использовал на Codigniter.То есть была общая модель в которой были описаны общие методы, и дальше из контроллера я вызывал данные методы просто передавая название таблицы.Можно ли реализовать подобное в Laravel использулья Eloquent?

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model{

    const USERS = 'users';
    const ORGS = 'organizations';
    const DEPS = 'departments';
    const CONTRS  = 'countries';

    public function save($table, $data){
        $query = $this->db->insert($table,$data);
        //$this->db->where_in('id', $array_row);
        if($query) return $this->db->insert_id(); 
        else return false;
    }

    public function saveAll($tabl, $data){
        $query = $this->db->insert_batch($table,$data);
        if($query) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public function update($table, $data, $id = null){
        if($id){    
          if(is_numeric($id)) $this->db->where('id_'.$table,$id);
          else $this->db->where($id);
        }    
        $result =  $this->db->update($table,$data);
        //$count = $this->db->affected_rows();
        return $result; 
    }

    public function delete($table, $cond){
        $query = $this->db->delete($table, $cond);
        return $query;
    }

    public function getRow($table, $arr = null){
        if($arr) $this->db->where($arr);
        $query = $this->db->get($table);
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function getAll($table, $cond_arr = null, $limit1 = null, $limit2 = null, $by_title = null, $order = null){  
        if(empty($limit2)) $limit2 = 0;
        if($limit1) $this->db->limit($limit1,$limit2);
        //$this->db->limit(5,5);
        if($cond_arr) $query = $this->db->where($cond_arr);        
        if($order and $by_title) $this->db->order_by($by_title, $order);
        $query = $this->db->get($table);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Пока что получилось такое реализовать.Общая модель и все остальные расширяют ее.

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class General extends Model{

        public static function getAll(){
            return self::all();
        }
    }

    ?>

    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Department extends General{

        protected $table = 'departments';
    }

    ?>

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Department;
use App\Models\User;

class MainController extends Controller{

    public function index(){
        $data['title'] = 'Blade Template';
        $data['departments'] = Department::getAll();
        $data['users'] = User::getAll();
        return view('main', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Если вы хотите работать с таблицами, для которых у вас описаны модели, то можно использовать стандартные методы Eloquent:

   ```
   Model::create(array('data' => 'data'));  

   $model = new Model();
   $model->data = data;
   $model->save();
   ```

   Пример для вставки. [Тут](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) написано подробнее.
   Также ничто не мешает переопределить эти методы в родительской модели, как вы и написали.
2. Если для таблиц моделей нет - то также можно воспользоваться стандартными методами Eloquent:

   ```
   Db::table('Table')->insert(array('data' => 'data')
   ```

   Подробнее [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts).